# about tree.DecisionTreeClassifier adjust class_weight

Tags: python, tree, classification

I have a unbalanced dataset, there are totally 209 rows (samples) which include 166 rows (class0) and 43 rows (class1).
Therefore, I want to solve the unbalanced problem,
then I used the python instruction to adjust the class weight.

```
tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4,class_weight={1:3.8})
clf.fit(scale_data, data_answer
```

Finally, in the result (fig.1), samples are still 209 but values became 166.0 (class0) and  166.34 (class1). The class1 samples the digits after decimal.
I can not  explain the result, even can not compile the source code which is written by Cpython (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L1948>)
Could anyone help me? 
Thank you.

[fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcAWk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class 1 doesn't "sample the digits after the decimal." I'm not sure what that even means. Instead, the samples are weighted, so the value is 43*3.8 = 163.4

Comment: the class weight is mean that doing oversampling to expand sample size?

Comment: @yating No. It's the weight given to the the class during training, it affects the outcome of the criterion function you choose for determining splits.